# expected struct `Vec`, found enum `Result` in tokio, cacache and match

Tags: web-scraping, rust, rust-tokio, reqwest

I find it difficult to understand what's wrong with the below code. I'm getting `expected struct Vec, found enum Result` error at `Ok(from_cache)`, but I have adopted the code from https://github.com/platy/update-tracker/blob/843092708906063704442f352231bfbac5b06196/server/src/web/mod.rs#L216-L226

During web scraping, I'm trying to cache the content of the URL in the cache and trying to reuse it.

```rust
use std::error::Error;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() ->  Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let url: &str = "https://example.com/";
    let html = match cacache::read("./cache", url).await? {
        Ok(from_cache) => String::from_utf8(from_cache),
        Err(_) => {
            let t_html = reqwest::get(url).await?.text().await?;
            cacache::write("./cache", url, &t_html).await?;
            t_html
        },
    };
    println!("html = {:?}", html);

    Ok(())
}
```

Here's the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a8c7fb25bd176ea33043f38631f813a2) (but, it shows other errors due to missing dependencies). Can anyone please explain this or share any relevant guide to gather more information about this topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that [the `?` operator unwraps a `Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator) (or `Option`) by propagating the `Err` (or `None`) case out of the current function.  Therefore, this expression:

```
cacache::read("./cache", url).await?
```

Has type `Vec<u8>` as the `?` operator has unwrapped the `Result`.  If you want to handle errors yourself, then omit the `?` operator:

```
cacache::read("./cache", url).await
```

Comment: I accepted your answer as it clears this particular issue. But, error now appears in subsequent lines at `String::from_utf8(from_cache)` with `this is found to be of type Result<std::string::String, FromUtf8Error>` and at `t_html` with `expected enum Result, found struct std::string::String` It clearly seems that I need to refer some good guides, but I can't seem to find anything for these.

Comment: @Rajesh `String::from_utf8` can fail on invalid encoding, so that also returns a `Result` which must be appropriately handled. If you _know_ that the conversion can't fail then you can `.unwrap()` it, which will panic if an error does occur.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still learning and trying it out

Comment: @Rajesh I'd suggest reading through the Rust book (linked in my answer) as it covers a lot of very useful topics that you might stumble over otherwise, particularly if you are coming from another programming language.